# How to aggregate Munin's interface traffic graphs?

Tags: monitoring, munin, rrdtool

My goal is to aggregate Munin's interface traffic graphs into one stacked graph for quick overview over the traffic across all servers.

This is the an example of an individual graph, I want to aggregate alongside other graphs of the same type.

[image: single server interface traffic graph]

Alongside my own implementation, I found several "solutions" (stack and sum) to this problem but none worked out the way I planned.

For example the following "homebrew" solution would aggregate/stack the outbound traffic correctly, however, the inbound traffic is completely omitted.

```
[exmaple.com;Totals]
    outside_traffic.graph_title Outbound traffic
    outside_traffic.graph_args --base 1000
    outside_traffic.graph_order down up
    outside_traffic.graph_category network
    outside_traffic.graph_vlabel bits in (-) / out (+) per ${graph_period}
    outside_traffic.graph_total Total
    outside_traffic.up.label outbound
    outside_traffic.up.type DERIVE
    outside_traffic.up.draw AREA
    outside_traffic.up.min 0
    outside_traffic.up.negative down
    outside_traffic.up.stack \
        kit-deu-01=kit-deu-01.example.com:if_enp0s31f6.up \
        pgsql1=pgsql1.example.com:if_eth0.up \
        proget1=proget1.example.com:if_eth0.up \
        redis1=redis1.example.com:if_eth0.up \
        salt=salt.example.com:if_eth0.up \
        secc=secc.example.com:if_eth0.up
    outside_traffic.down.label inbound
    outside_traffic.down.type DERIVE
    outside_traffic.down.draw AREA
    outside_traffic.down.graph no
    outside_traffic.down.min 0
    outside_traffic.down.stack \
        kit-deu-01=kit-deu-01.example.com:if_enp0s31f6.down \
        pgsql1=pgsql1.example.com:if_eth0.down \
        proget1=proget1.example.com:if_eth0.down \
        redis1=redis1.example.com:if_eth0.down \
        salt=salt.example.com:if_eth0.down \
        secc=secc.example.com:if_eth0.down
```

[image: wrong aggregated graph]

I also tried to omit `outside_traffic.down.graph no`, but this also have no effect.

How to aggregate the graph correctly, so it will aggregate positive (outbound) and negative (inbound) traffic in one graph like the individual source graphs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem like this is directly possible, because the documentation at http://guide.munin-monitoring.org/en/latest/develop/plugins/plugin-bcp.html#direction explicitly describes the `negative` direction parameter as a "hack"

I'd assume there's a way if it is possible to use CDEF, but I don't see it at this point, googling produces only complaints about it not working :)